# Dropdown won't select and open div... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary

On our [Offices](https://www.bensoncompany.co.uk/offices/) page if you click the dots on the map it opens a div below and changes the sidebar contents. We added a dropdown so you could select cities on mobiles. Since I recreated the website and copied over the code I've done something and it doesn't work anymore.

I know the problem has something to do with this bit of code

```
$('#continent').change(function() {
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#worldwide').hide();
    var target = $("select option:selected").attr('target');
    var value = $("select option:selected").attr('value');
    console.log($('#' + value));
    $(".detail-container").empty();
    $('#' + value).clone().show().appendTo(
        ".detail-container");
    $('#div' + target).show();
    if (value == "worldwide") {
        $('.slidingDiv').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Here is the full code

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $(".dot").show();

    $('.dot').click(function() {

        $(".slidingDiv").slideDown('slow');

    });

    $('#continent').change(function() {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideDown('slow');
    });
});

jQuery(function($) {

    $('#showSingle').click(function() {

        $('.targetDiv').show();

    });

    $('.dot').click(function() {
        $('.targetDiv').hide();
        $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
        var value = $(this).attr('city');
        $(".detail-container").empty();
        $('#' + value).clone().show().appendTo(
            ".detail-container");
        $('#' + value).show();
        $('#continent').val(value);
    });

    $('#continent').change(function() {
        $('.targetDiv').hide();
        $('#worldwide').hide();
        var target = $("select option:selected").attr('target');
        var value = $("select option:selected").attr('value');
        console.log($('#' + value));
        $(".detail-container").empty();
        $('#' + value).clone().show().appendTo(
            ".detail-container");
        $('#div' + target).show();
        if (value == "worldwide") {
            $('.slidingDiv').slideUp();
        }
    });

});
```

I'm sure this is something simple for someone who knows Javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: You should check the console for errors - `Uncaught ReferenceError: getenv is not defined`  Fix that first.  It may well be the only problem.

Comment: I checked and that is something to do with calling the analytics so it shouldn't be affecting it.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
$('#continent').change(function() {
        $('.targetDiv').hide();
        $('#worldwide').hide();
        var target = $("#continent").find(":selected").attr('target');
        var value = $("#continent").val();
        console.log($('#' + value));
        $(".detail-container").empty();
        $('#' + value).clone().show().appendTo(
            ".detail-container");
        $('#div' + target).show();
        if (value == "worldwide") {
            $('.slidingDiv').slideUp();
        }
    });
```

Should work, but it's very ugly code i guess :P